# select statement in sql server to select every other row on alternate basis

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

we have a table named "Result" have only one column say "Result".
It contains 12 rows. First 6 rows contains "pass" and the next 6 rows contains "fail"

```
Result
---------------------
pass
pass
pass
pass
pass
pass
fail
fail
fail
fail
fail
fail
```

Now what would be the statement in  SQL Query to return the return like below

```
Expected Result:-
pass
fail
pass
fail
pass
fail
pass
fail
pass
fail
pass
fail
```

Number of record may be in thousands but Query should work for all

Comment: I think you've oversimplified this.  It looks like you don't want to select every other row, but select rows alternating from the first half of the table and the second half?  Are there any other columns that can be used to differentiate?

Comment: Sounds like a very broken database design in the first place.

Comment: Also: is it possible for the number of pass/fail records to become unbalanced (more of one kind than the other)? What do you want to happen in that scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in fact you need:
the sequence of: `one row from end, one row from beginning,...and so on until all rows get selected` so make all passes as `ODD` and all fails as `EVEN`, now you can simply select and order by the number you made:

```
with CTE as
(
  select result , row_number() over(partition by result order by result) as rn
  from result
)
select result,
  case
  when result='fail' then rn*2 else rn*2 -1  end rn
from CTE 
order by rn
```

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/aca81/1)

Answer (score 0):

select result from (select row_number() over( order by result ) row_num,result from result where result='fail'
union 
select row_number() over( order by result ) row_num,result from result where result='pass')a
order by row_num

Works in Mssql